# Does my Edimax BR-6524n support Tomato or DD-WRT?

Tags: router, dd-wrt, tomato

I have an Edimax BR-6524n router.  The Edimax website says it has 4 MB NOR Flash and 
16 MB SDRAM.

Can I install Tomato or DD-WRT on it?  These are the ones that [Jeff recommends](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/because-everyone-needs-a-router.html), and I want to try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's supported by neither.

From http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato:

> Routers that are known to work with Tomato:
>
> - Linksys WRT54G v1-v4, WRT54GS v1-v4, WRT54GL v1.x, WRTSL54GS (no USB support)
> - Buffalo WHR-G54S, WHR-HP-G54, WZR-G54, WBR2-G54, WBR-G54, WZR-HP-G54, WZR-RS-G54, WZR-RS-G54HP, WVR-G54-NF, WHR2-A54-G54, WHR3-AG54
> - Asus WL500G Premium (no USB support), WL500GE, WL520GU (no USB support)
> - Sparklan WX6615GT, Fuji RT390W, Microsoft MN-700

http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database does not list it as supported.

Comment: That list seems far from exhaustive, as I can name two routers that can run Tomato that are not listed, off the top of my head: Asus RT-N16 and Netgear WNR3500L. Basically, there are many forks off Tomato. DD-WRT supports a more routers - not just ones with Broadcom chipsets.

Comment: Hence my answer it's not *supported*, not *you can't* ;)

Answer (score 0):

OpenWRT supports it apparently since 2013: https://dev.archive.openwrt.org/ticket/12754

DD-WRT: https://wikidevi.com/wiki/Edimax_BR-6524n, https://forum.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=66672